# On probability of coprime integers.

Tags: probability, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Suppose if we pick *odd* $a,b$ randomly in $(t_1,t_2)$ where $0<t_1<b<a<t_2<\infty$ holds the probability that $(a,b)=1$ holds is $\frac1{\zeta(2)}$.

What is the probability that if we pick *odd* $a,b$ randomly in $(t_1,t_2)$ where $0<t_1<b<a<t_2<\infty$ holds then $(a,b)=(\frac{a+b}2,\frac{a-b}2)=1$ holds? Is it $\frac1{\zeta(2)^2}$?

Comment: The $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$ probability for two numbers to be coprime is when you allow even numbers. For only odd numbers, it is $\frac{8}{\pi^2}$. (Both are technically not probabilities of course, and when you restrict the range to be able to pick from a uniform distribution the actual probability is only approximately that [and only for large ranges].) The second condition adds nothing, for odd $a,b$ we have $$\biggl(\frac{a+b}{2},\frac{a-b}{2}\biggr) = \biggl(\frac{a+b}{2},a\biggr) = (a+b,a) = (b,a)\,.$$